# Can python simultaneously listen to multiple clients and execute commands

Tags: python

I want to have server to listen to multiple clients whist it processes data that it has acquired from previous messages and sends out messages of its own. Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and see if you should rephrase your question.

Comment: **It is possible !** ...